# How to kill a tree of processes started by child_process?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have Node.js app that spawns processes using `child_process.spawn(my_command)`. I use it to run commands like `sudo my-app`.

When the `sudo` process starts, it starts `my-app`. So I end up with a tree of processes. `sudo` at the top, my app, my server, etc. at the bottom.

From my node script, if I kill the process I started: `my_process.kill("SIGTERM")`, it kills the `sudo` process but not its children. My server keeps running.

Is there a way to kill the whole tree of processes?

Comment: What operating system are you using? What function you are creating a child process? spawn or exec? child.pid contains pid of sudo or child process?